# How to get arguments from PLESK Cron jobs

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I have created a Cron Job/Scheduled Task in PLESK 12 which I am passing the arguments 33 and On through using the arguments box. I am struggling to pick these up in the PHP document on the end of the cron job.

[image: PLESK and Arguments]

In the PHP document I have tried a number of things including $arg[0] and $argv[0]

$arg returned as being an undefined variable whilst $argv[0] does not error but also does not pass the arguments through successfully as the desired changed has not been made.

I have checked to ensure the PHP script is working and it works fine when the arguments are hard coded into the program but I want this to be dynamic.

```
<?PHP
include_once('xxx/xxx/xxx/db.php');
include('xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/db.php');
$query = "UPDATE SQLCommand SET argument1 = '$argv[1]' WHERE argument2= $argv[0]";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Can anyone explain why these are still not passing the arguments through.

Thanks

Comment: `$argv[0]` always contains the name of the script file.
As per screenshot, `$argv[1]` is '33' and `$argv[2]` is 'On'. You can easily check with `echo $argv[1];`.

Comment: @ElvisPlesky Thanks for this I will give it a shot and let you know. Appreciate it .

Comment: @ElvisPlesky Please can you put your response as an answer rather than a comment, this has worked perfectly and would like to make sure you get the rep for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$argv[0]` always contains the name of the script file, as it passed to the PHP binary.
As per screenshot, `$argv[1]` is '33' and `$argv[2]` is 'On'. You can easily check with:

```
echo $argv[1];
```

Or you can list all arguments as an array by:

```
var_dump($argv);
```

Basically, the following task is added to crontab, when scheduled via Plesk:

```
/usr/bin/php5 -f '/test.php' -- '33' 'On'
```

If `test.php` contains mentioned commands, the result of its' execution will be the following:

```
# cat /test.php
<?php
echo "The first argument is $argv[1]\n";
echo "Here the full list of arguments:\n";
var_dump($argv);
?>
# /usr/bin/php5 -f '/test.php' -- '33' 'On'
The first argument is 33
Here the full list of arguments:
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "/test.php"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "33"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "On"
}
```